# how to decrease time complexity in python?

Tags: python

Given a paragraph  of space-separated lowercase English words and a list of unique lowercase English keywords, find the minimum length of the substring of  which contains all the keywords that are separated by space in any order.

i put the following code where is the error ? How can i decrease time complexity.

```
import sys
def minimumLength(text, keys):
    answer = 10000000
    text += " $"
    for i in xrange(len(text) - 1):
        dup = list(keys)
        word = ""
        if i > 0 and text[i - 1] != ' ':
            continue

        for j in xrange(i, len(text)):
            if text[j] == ' ':
                for k in xrange(len(dup)):
                    if dup[k] == word:
                        del(dup[k])
                        break
                word = ""
            else:
                word += text[j]
            if not dup:
                answer = min(answer, j - i)
                break

    if(answer == 10000000):
        answer = -1

    return answer
text = raw_input()
keyWords = int(raw_input())
keys = []
for i in xrange(keyWords):
    keys.append(raw_input())
print(minimumLength(text, keys))
```

Comment: This has all the characteristics of a school assignment. These types of questions are generally not welcome here. And if you are going to post code, please provide why the code isn't working. Thank you.

Comment: @Torxed - Whether or not its a school assignment is irrelevant, all that matters is that a question follows the [ask] guidelines.

Comment: Also, since question is about time complexity, can you show us your calculations of time complexity and what's your exact problem with it? Hint: Your are using three for loops  with two of them going to `n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to scan from left to right and, once you find a window containing all the keys, try to reduce it on the left and enlarge it on the right preserving the property that all the terms remain inside the window.

Using this strategy you can solve the task in linear time.
The following code is a draft of the code that I tested on few strings, I hope the comments are enough to highlight the most critical steps:

---

```
def minimum_length(text, keys):
    assert isinstance(text, str) and (isinstance(keys, set) or len(keys) == len(set(keys)))
    minimum_length = None
    key_to_occ = dict((k, 0) for k in keys)
    text_words = [word if word in key_to_occ else None for word in text.split()]
    missing_words = len(keys)
    left_pos, last_right_pos = 0, 0

    # find an interval with all the keys
    for right_pos, right_word in enumerate(text_words):
        if right_word is None:
            continue
        key_to_occ[right_word] += 1
        occ_word = key_to_occ[right_word]
        if occ_word == 1:  # the first time we see this word in the current interval
            missing_words -= 1
            if missing_words == 0:  # we saw all the words in this interval
                key_to_occ[right_word] -= 1
                last_right_pos = right_pos
                break

    if missing_words > 0:
        return None

    # reduce the interval on the left and enlarge it on the right preserving the property that all the keys are inside
    for right_pos in xrange(last_right_pos, len(text_words)):
        right_word = text_words[right_pos]
        if right_word is None:
            continue
        key_to_occ[right_word] += 1
        while left_pos < right_pos:  # let's try to reduce the interval on the left
            left_word = text_words[left_pos]
            if left_word is None:
                left_pos += 1
                continue
            if key_to_occ[left_word] == 1:  # reduce the interval only if it doesn't decrease the number of occurrences
                interval_size = right_pos + 1 - left_pos
                if minimum_length is None or interval_size < minimum_length:
                    minimum_length = interval_size
                break
            else:
                left_pos += 1
                key_to_occ[left_word] -= 1
    return minimum_length
```